# Windows Update continuous failing on Server 2019

Tags: windows-update, hyper-v, windows-server-2019

I have an on-prem Server 2019 Hyper-V VM and ever since January 2023, the "Cumulative" Windows Updates have been failing. It's been about 3 months now and there are about 3 different KB numbers that have failed and I cannot seem to figure out why. I have tried every possible thing that I could find online but the updates are still failing. The updates have been failing with error code - 0x8007000D. Can you please help?

Edit: The installation on the Windows Updates screen shows successful. But upon restart, it says "Failed to update, Undoing Changes" and it restarts again.

Things that I have tried are: Update Troubleshooter sfc \scannow dism Utility Manual Download of the KB number from Windows Catalog Reset Windows Components

I have also checked the CBS logs and attached screenshot is what I have found. Not sure if it is relevant or not
[image: Failed Error]

Comment: If you manually download the update are you able to install the update. There are far to many reasons a system might receive 0x8007000D to troubleshoot with the amount of information you have provided.

Comment: Short Answer- No.
What actually happens is that when I "install" the updates, they go through without errors but when I restart to finish the installation, it says "Failed to update, undoing changes" and then restarts again.

Comment: So you downloaded the current cumulative update from the Windows Update Catalog, ran and installed the file, and encountered an error after a restart? I am trying to understand how corrupt your system is, DO NOT attempt to install the update through Windows Update.  Download it manually from the Windows Update Catalog website and install it.

Comment: Follow these [troubleshooting instructions](https://ugetfix.com/ask/how-to-fix-error-code-0x8007000d-on-windows-10/) and test.

Comment: @Ramhound I have downloaded and installed the updates from Windows Catalog but it does the exact same thing.

Comment: @harrymc - I have followed said instructions to the T and some more (that I was able to find on other articles and forums) and it still doesn't make any difference.

Comment: All that I can see in addition is to [Perform an in-place upgrade of Windows Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/perform-in-place-upgrade). Backup your data first, and perhaps save a disk image and ensure you can return it via boot from USB.

Comment: Before doing an in-place upgrade run `DISM /Online /CheckHealth`

Comment: I don't see any other options either.
Thank you for your responses fellas. Much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to check the disk space on your machine and make sure there are sufficient space for the update to download and install.

I encountered this before where my server disk space was filling up and the windows update was unable to complete downloading with errors.

alternatively, please check on the windows update database on your C:\ and delete the old DB and download a fresh new one. Most probably the previous win update DB is corrupted and can't be used.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Ended up creating a new server. Thank you though.